# List Add() method doest seem to work in my script. Count of elements in list is 0 after i add some of them in forach loop

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm relatively new to C# (Learned some Java in school, thouhh) so my appologies if I made some stupid mistakes in my code. :)

I've encountered a strange situation in my script task which is included in my SSIS package. What I'm trying to do is to Recursively iterate over some local directory and get paths of every excel file that includes some pattern string. Next I want to assign these strings to a List, so I can pass it to a SSIS User Variable.

To test if I get the proper strings I wrote this line:

```c#
MessageBox.Show(f);  //TEST
```

Here is an example of path:

```
L:\Wyciagi Bankowe\BZ WBK\2016\2016-01\wk01.16 01.01-05.01.2016\wk01 9329 _weekly.xls
```

And everything seems to work fine... until I try to iterate over the list which apparently is empty.

```c#
MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());  // this returns 0
foreach (String item in list)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

I've been reading through stackoverflow and some MSDN documentation and everything seems to be exactly the same or very similar to the examples. 
Sooo... What Im i doing wrong? :) I've been trying to resolve this for hours now and I don't have any more ideas...

Here's my script. Sorry for pasting the entire code, but I don't know what part would be useful.
If you have any questions, please let me know.

```c#
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    private String path; 
    private List<String> list;

    public void Main()
    {
        path =  Dts.Variables["Working_DIR"].Value.ToString();

        DirSearch(path);

        //TEST START
        MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());  

        foreach (String item in list)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item);
        }
        // TEST END

        Dts.Variables["File_List"].Value = list;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        String searchPattern = "*9329*.xls";
        list = new List<String>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                if (d.Contains("2016") || d.Contains("2017") || d.Contains("2018") || d.Contains("2019"))
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, searchPattern))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(f);  //TEST
                        list.Add(f);
                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }

        }

        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };


}
```

Comment: You seem to recreate the list every time in `DirSearch()`, including recursive subcalls; is that the problem?

Comment: OMG I think You're right ;) Let me check. :D

Comment: @Sławek `someone` is right, move `list = new List<String>();` to `Main` and out of the `DirSearch`... or declare it like `private List<String> list = new List<String>();`

Comment: You might want to study about out and ref keywords. The list is being initialised every time. So either use ref keyword, or change private List<String> list; to private List<String> list = new List<string>(); and remove list = new List<String>(); inside DirSearch.

Comment: Also, as a side-note, I know you have studied Java and wrote String instead of string. Firstly, both of them are right, but C# developers prefer string to match C# code styling. You can also change it to var altogether. e.g:  String searchPattern = "*9329*.xls"; can be changed to  var searchPattern = "*9329*.xls";

Comment: Thank You @someone that was it. I just move the init of the List to the calss field and it works fine. I knew it was something stupid... ;)

Comment: @Amir No-Family thanks for advice i'll keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line in the DirSearch method:

```
list = new List<String>();
```

Every time you call it recursively, it is setting the list back to an empty list. The better option would be to initialize the list from the main method.

If you want to maintain a separate list inside of DirSearch, you can create a list variable local to the method and then add it to the class level list by using the AddRange list method.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ When I opened the question, there were no comments yet.